# Android Gradle issue?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I imported an application in Android studio(the newest Android Studio version), and I tried everything like: uninstall and install the JDK again, re-apply for each library, updating the SDK manager, the code is before 5-6 years ago, so now im trying to update the Gradle and I couldn't fix this issue.

build.gradle(modules:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.App"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 29
    }compile

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
    compileSdkVersion = 29
}

dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/asmack-issue-13.jar')
    implementation files('libs/gcm.jar')
    implementation files('libs/gson-1.7.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.1-beta1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/mediationsdk-6.4.17.jar')
    implementation files('libs/PayPalAndroidSDK.jar')
}
```

Gradle-wrapper.propertis

```
#Mon Jan 27 05:34:23 GST 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

Project Gradle

```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
```

The error

```
Total time: 12.797 secs
ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()'
Possible causes:
The project 'App_copy' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 3.5.1 and sync project

The project 'App_copy' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin
```

Comment: Hmm.  Strange; the `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'` should have set what gradle plugin you're using, already, I think.  Try right clicking on your project, click "Open Module Settings", then click "Project" in the segment on the left.  It should give you some dropdowns "Android Gradle Plugin Version" and "Gradle Version".  Make sure the former is at 3.5.1 like it should be, or change it until it is (or is a higher version).  You COULD also change the second one ("Gradle Version"), but I don't know what to.  Mine is at 5.4.1.

Comment: Thanks, @Erhannis , this fixed the error, steps I made: "Open Module Settings" then "Project" > Change the Gradle version to 5.4.1 then sync it again it will fix the error

Comment: Glad to hear it.  In general, on Stack Overflow, when a successful solution has been found, the questioner marks the solution "correct", so others with the same problem can find it more easily.  For that purpose, I've created an answer based on my comment.  There should be a checkmark to the left of it, which will mark the answer "correct".  Good luck with your programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your project, click "Open Module Settings", then click "Project" in the segment on the left. It should give you some dropdowns "Android Gradle Plugin Version" and "Gradle Version". Make sure the former is at 3.5.1 like it should be, or change it until it is (or is a higher version). You COULD also change the second one ("Gradle Version"), but I don't know what to. Mine is at 5.4.1.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Add google maven repo like that in top level gradle file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }       
        google()
    }
}
```

and

1. Build
2. clean project

then

1. Open android studio
2. Click file (in the top bar)
3. Invalidate caches and restart
4. again Invalidate caches and restart

---

Try this (You missed many things in your app level gradle file)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.App"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}
}
```

And your implementation files(libraries) may be out dated, please try to update it or use maven repo instead of jar file

Comment: Didn't fix the error, still im getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you need to use a old Android Studio version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).